# How will adjusted r-squared is equal to r-squared?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I know that when all observation fall in the fitted regression line, then

$$SSE = 0$$ and  $$R^2 = 1$$
Hence, $\bar{R}^2 = R^2$. Are there any conditions under which $\bar{R}^2 = R^2$?

Comment: Downvoting my questions (including mcnemar's test) without reliable reason is just a troll who also doesn't the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
R_{adj}^2 &= 1 - \frac{(1-R^2)(n-1)}{n-k-1} \\
\textrm{ assuming } R_{adj}^2 &= R^2 \Rightarrow R^2 = 1 - \frac{(1-R^2)(n-1)}{n-k-1} \\ 0 &= (1 - R^2) - \frac{(1-R^2)(n-1)}{n-k-1} \\ (1-R^2)\left( 1 - \frac{n-1}{n-k-1} \right) &= 0 \Rightarrow 1-R^2 = 0 \textrm{ or } \left( 1 - \frac{n-1}{n-k-1} \right) = 0 \\
R^2 &= 1 \textrm{ or } \frac{n-1}{n-k-1}=1 \\
\textrm{ assuming  } n-k-1 &\ne 0 \Rightarrow n-1 = n-k-1 \Rightarrow k=0 \\ &(\textrm{ hence the assumption } n-k-1 \ne \textrm{is valid}) \\
\end{align*}

hence, $R_{adj}^2 = R^2$ only under the following 2 conditions:

1. $R^2 = 1$
2. k=0 , i.e. no features exist.

The 2nd point will not hold for X vs. Y types of prediction tasks and will only hold for autoregression and other time-series analysis methods.
Hence, for a typical X vs. Y prediction task , $R_{adj}^2 = R^2$ only when $R^2 = 1$.

Comment: oh see, I knew I'm close to understanding the problem. thanks man.

Comment: hey @Kadpirox if you understood the answer, you could help out a fellow new contributor by upvoting/accepting it. thanks !!!

Comment: Sure man. Already upvoted.